# Visual Studio 2013 Intellisense not working

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

I have Visual Studio 2013 Professional with Update 2 RC installed. I tried to add new projects using ASP.NET SPA Template, AngularStart and a few other SPA templates. None of them showing intellisense even the VS can't determine the user defined class types, as their font color is black, GoToDefinition option is disabled in context menu, and I can't see the suggestions drop-down while typing or while accessing class methods through instance.

I reset the settings files many times from Import Export option. I also tried "devenv /setup" but didn't work. At the end I uninstalled and re-installed the VS 2013, still having the same problem.

I tried adding a new Web API project with "Individual User Accounts", intellisense works. But when i added a new Web API project without authentication and later i installed nuget package Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin, now intellisense stops working.

**Edit:**

I am getting this problem in almost every project. when I close the newly created project and reopen it, the problem arise. And when I unload and reload the project in solution, then everything starts working. So I have to unload and reload the projects each time I open a solution in visual studio.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's the same thing, but I recently had a project's Intellisense in VS 2013 stop working too. If I cleaned the solution and rebuilt it, it would work for a very short time but then stop again soon. Lots of wavy red underlines too where there shouldn't have been.

For me, I closed VS and deleted the the solution's `.suo` file (in the solution's root). (Keep in mind this will also delete your breakpoints, bookmarks, and other user-preferences. But nothing "code"-related.) You might also try deleting the `csproj.user` files as well. I guess it just got corrupted or who knows. But haven't had a problem with it since.

I hope this helps!